# RollingFileAppender doesn't create the log file

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

When i use RollingFileAppender, it doesn't create the log file, but if I use FileAppender it creates the log file.
with fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(); no log file is created.
with fileAppender = new FileAppender(); log file is created.

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender;

public class LoggerUtils {
    private static final String FILE_APPENDER = "FILE_APPENDER";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Logger foo = createLoggerFor("foo");
        Logger bar = createLoggerFor("bar");
        foo.info("this is from foo log");
        bar.info("this is from bar log");
    }

    private static Logger createLoggerFor(String string) {
        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        
        PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n");
        ple.setContext(lc);
        ple.start();
        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        fileAppender.setFile("test_two.log");
        fileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
        fileAppender.setContext(lc);
        fileAppender.start();

        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.setAdditive(false);
        logger.warn("Testing....");

        return logger;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) you must specify both a `RollingPolicy` and a `TriggeringPolicy`. Here is the quote from that link:

> To be of any use, a RollingFileAppender must have both a RollingPolicy and a TriggeringPolicy set up.

Also

> However, if its RollingPolicy also implements the TriggeringPolicy interface, then only the former needs to be specified explicitly.

And indeed, if you look into the source code of `RollingFileAppender` [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.java#L52) and [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/55502546142897ef6d579568ac8ec8933577e88a/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.java#L74) you will see that there are "not-null" preconditions on those policies:

```
public void start() {
    if (triggeringPolicy == null) {
        addWarn("No TriggeringPolicy was set for the RollingFileAppender named " + getName());
        addWarn(MORE_INFO_PREFIX + RFA_NO_TP_URL);
        return; // BOOM
    }
    ...
    if (rollingPolicy == null) {
        addError("No RollingPolicy was set for the RollingFileAppender named " + getName());
        addError(MORE_INFO_PREFIX + RFA_NO_RP_URL);
        return; // BOOM
    }
    ...
}
```

So, to remediate the situation your relevant piece of code can be like the below if you use the standard [`TimeBasedRollingPolicy`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy) which is:

> TimeBasedRollingPolicy is possibly the most popular rolling policy. It defines a rollover policy based on time, for example by day or by month.

```
RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<>();
fileAppender.setFile("test_two.log");
fileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
fileAppender.setContext(lc);

TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> logFilePolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<>();
logFilePolicy.setContext(lc);
logFilePolicy.setParent(fileAppender);
logFilePolicy.setFileNamePattern("test_two.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}");
logFilePolicy.setMaxHistory(7);
logFilePolicy.start();

fileAppender.setRollingPolicy(logFilePolicy);
fileAppender.start();
```

Using this code I can see the configured `test_two.log` file being always created.